# How does this insertion and deletion logic from a hashtable work?

Tags: c++, pointers, hashtable

I have been struggling to understand how this works for a while in gdb but I'm having a hard time understanding it. Basically there is an array (`elements_`) into which things are hashed, these things are pointers to structs containing certain hooks used for the chaining. Here is a sample struct:

```
struct foo
{
    Data  data;
    foo*  next;
    foo** prevNext;
};
```

then the hash table gets instantiated with

```
HashTable<foo> hash;
```

and it's insertion function looks like this (i've ommitted the resizing and all for simplicity)

```
template <class T>
void HashTable<T>::insert(T* x)
{
    int bucket  = hashFunc(x->data);
    T** xPtr    = &elements_[bucket];
    x->next     = *xPtr;
    x->prevNext = xPtr;

    if (x->next)
        x->next->prevNext = &x->next;

    *xPtr = x;
}
```

and the removal is as follows

```
template<class T>
void HashTable<T>::remove(T* x)
{
    if (x->next)
        x->next->prevNext = x->prevNext;

    *x->prevNext = x->next;
}
```

And for reference the way it is searched is like this:

```
template<class T>
T* HashTable<T>::find(Data& data)
{
    int bucket = hashFunc(data);

    T* ptr = elements_[bucket];
    while (ptr != 0)
    {
        if(ptr->data == data)
            return ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I keep trying to follow insertion of 2-3 colliding elements (by setting the table size to be small to begin with) and deletions to see what the logic is but I'm not understanding it. Here is a diagram of what I think the removal operation (removing node 2) is doing, though it's still a bit fuzzy in my head:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements that fall into the same bucket are stored as a doubly-linked list (sort of).

Lookup traverses that list until it finds an element with matching `data` value.

Comment: Yes, what I don't understand is the implementation of the "sort of doubly linked list"

Comment: @PalaceChan: Well, every node contains a pointer to the next node (the "next pointer"), and a pointer to the previous node's next pointer.

Comment: The next pointer is ok but the latter is a double pointer to the previous node, not its next pointer that I can tell. I'm confused on that regard, why a double pointer and how the linking/unlinking logic works.

Comment: @PalaceChan: Good stuff. If you can think yourself through such constructions, you can eventually understand everything :-)